# Finding a finite Galois cover trivializing a lisse sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Given a lisse $\mathbb{F}_{\ell^r}$-sheaf on a smooth curve $U$ defined ofer $\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$, Katz says [here, in p. 33](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nmk/Katz-GKM.pdf), that $\mathcal{F}$ "becomes constant on some connected finite etale galois covering $E \rightarrow U$". Why is this true?

If $\mathcal{F}$ is just an etale sheaf of $\mathbb{F}_\ell$-modules, this is similar to Prop. 7.6 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.6899v2.pdf), but I don't know how to conclude the statement for the lisse sheaf and I haven't found any reference explicit enough.

EDIT: $\mathcal{F}$ corresponds to a continuous homomorphism $\pi_1(U, \bar{x}) \rightarrow GL_r(\mathbb{F}_\ell)$, and the target is finite, so we get a surjection onto the image $\pi_1(U, \bar{x}) \rightarrow G$. Somehow this surjection should correspond to a Galois cover of $U$ that trivializes $\mathcal{F}$, but I'm not sure how to see this explicitely.

Comment: the kernel of that surjection corresponds (by defn of $\pi_1$) to a finite Galois cover of $U$. This cover obviously trivializes $\mathcal{F}$ (b/c the image of $\pi_1(\text{cover})$ in $GL_r(\mathbb{F}_\ell)$ is trivial).

Comment: Note that this would not have been possible if we had been dealing with a lisse $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-sheaf since, in that case, the kernel of the corresponding representation is not open.